# phonegap ios bundle identifier not matching

Tags: cordova

I did a build on phonegap and everything is good but when i went to submit the app through iTunes Connect, I got an error saying that the bundle identifier do not match. When submitting to phonegap, the instructions say to submit html, css and javascript files and I am wondering where the identifier has to be changed.

Part 2 to this question is that I using google analytics plugin how do I make sure it is oresent in the package that the phonegap build produces?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Not sure what version of Cordova you are using, so this answer is based on 3.1.0

Your bundle identifier should be set by Cordova. Look at the `www/config.xml` file in your project. The bundle identifier is the `id` attribute of the root `widget` element:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="your.bundle.identifier" version="0.0.1" ...
```

When you build your project for iOS this should be set as the identifier. If this does not seem to be the case for you, check the generated XCode project in `platforms/ios` by opening on it and clicking the topmost icon on the left of the UI:

[image: XCode displaying project name]

(As for the Google Analytics question, I'm not 100% sure what you're asking. You'll get better results on Stack Overflow if you ask this as a separate question.)

Answer (score 1):

You can change or check out the **bundle identifier** if you go on your project in Xcode and click on **"General" tab** or you go to your app-Info.plist file in resources folder and change the **bundle identifier** in there.
Also check if the BI is the same in the **"Info" tab** of your project.

***But most likely the problem is not inside your project*** , since you mentioned that the error occurs during app submission. You probably set a different **Bundle ID** in **ItunesConnect** than in your project. In iTunesConnect go to "Manage Apps" - choose your app - and on the left check Bundle ID.

Also note that the **Bundle ID** is case sensitive. Since you can't change the Bundle ID inside ITC once you entered it there you need to change it in your project.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to find where the bundle identifier was being set in the Cordova build.  Turns out that in file project.pbxproj, PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER was not being updated with the new bundle ID.

Overwriting this manually then rebuilding was the fix.